# Windows 10 - Mist Wallet freezes

Tags: mist, wallets

I'm a first time user, reading a book and ready to try some experimentation. 
I downloaded the wallet (Ethereum-Wallet-installer-0-8-10.exe), and it froze on the following screen for at 8 or more hours (I thought maybe it was downloading, but I don't think it ever got that far).

[image]

The circle image was animated, which implied to me it was doing something and I should wait. I think the above was the screen after I entered my password.

Also expected the "Checking Network..." in upper right corner to go away, or the "connecting to 2 peers" to change to some other text.

Comment: Hmm well just to note, if it's your first time, then you're also downloading the blockchain. You do have the option to first let it download and then try making an account afterwards. Other than that I have no clue, just a suggestion.

Comment: A watched a video on installing the wallet - and when it was downloading the blockchain, it showed that status on the status bar at the bottom (where mine says "Connecting to 2 peers..."

Comment: For now, I've gone back to 8.09 of the wallet and things seems to be moving forward. I tried 8.10 on a different computer and had the same problem there. I'm a first time user, so wasn't 100% sure what to expect from the screens.

Comment: See also: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9313/how-do-i-find-out-how-big-the-chain-structure-is-for-a-particular-block - this is what I'm facing now.  Very frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Parity** instead of **Mist**.

Parity Ethereum client is very light and fast (UI runs in your browser), syncing up is not a problem. 
It can do everything Mist does, including Sending/Receiving Ether, and Writing/Compiling/Deploying Solidity smart contracts.

Most importantly, it doesn't hang my Windows laptop, unlike Mist. 
Heck, even Vitalik Buterin uses Parity!

Github releases:
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases

Official website:
https://parity.io/parity.html

Good luck Neal!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm taking several courses and most of them have been referring to Mist, but I'll give it a try.  I'm wondering if the problems are the Test network and not Mist?  The course I just started shows how to build a private network to test on.